# Approval Workflow mid-Workflow Versioning

Tags: workflow, approval

So this is my situation,
Using the pre-build approval workflow, I will send email to 2 other (Person A and B) in serial. A and B and Me all have full control on the document. Let's say I already started the workflow and now the task is on Person A. However, I now wish to make changes to document, so I check out and later check it in.
Is there any version control way I can ensure to make Person A see the "latest" version of the changes I made? (as the task is still pending on him)

Or does this sounds illogical as because it is a Approval Workflow, No changes should be made unless Person A/B click the [Request Change] button back to Me.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: From an approval process view point the document should not be allowed to be edited during the approval process is running. As what is being approved is the document at the start of the approval process, if a user is changing it in the middle of the process then there is no guarantee that the intended document is approved.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the Approval workflow configuration to cancel all approval tasks if the document is changed. If you tick this option, then in your scenario, the workflow will cancel on your change and will need to be restarted for Person A to see the changes.

Comment: HI thanks for replying, i am aware of the "tick" option, but that would result in me having to restart the whole approval process again right?, Im wondering if it is possible to "edit" the file midway and still allowing the Person A or B to see the "edited" version. Sorry for the confusion